# vuejs - How to prevent a component from responding to a global event

Tags: vue.js

I have a global event firing from a select box change.

I have component A which responds to the event and redirects.

I have component B which also responds to the event and redirects.

I have component C which responds to the event and loads some data.

Only one component is visible at a time, on its own "page" (route). The select  box is on all pages.

What is happening is I select an option and all components A B and C are responding, causing a redirection fight and total hysteria.

I would expect that when component C is displayed, Component A and B are not displayed and therefore will not respond to the event.

What am I missing? I have attempted many combinations of  `v-if` , `Mounted()`, `Ready()` and `beforeDestroy()` but these not "loaded" components are still responding to events......

#### Here is some code:

1) registering the event (in main.js)
`window.EventBus = new Vue();`

2) adding an event when a select option is changed:
`EventBus.$emit('studentSelectLoaded')`

3) catching the event in components:

```
EventBus.$on('studentSelectedEvent', function(){
        gd();})
```

## What I did to get it working:

1) I have a dataReady property in data:

```
data() {
            return {
                data: {},
                dataReady: false,
                loading: false,
                searchableTable: null,
                route: 'coursework_list'

            }
        },
```

2) Before destroy I set data ready to false:

```
beforeDestroy(){
            this.dataReady = false;
         },
```

3) Add in a check on the event listener:

```
EventBus.$on('studentSelectedEvent', function(){
                if(self.dataReady){
                    gd();

                }
            })
```

I am registering the components as children of a page which is loaded via a route, so when the page is not loaded I would expect the component is not loaded.

Here is a page:

```
<template>
    <div class="components">
        <zzi-courseworklist></zzi-courseworklist>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import zzicourseworklist from "../../components/studentParent/CourseWorkList/CourseWorkList"
export default{
    components:{
        'zzi-courseworklist': zzicourseworklist 
    }

}
</script>
```

Any more thoughts?

Comment: a tried code or an example could give us a start point to help you

Comment: Unsolveable without showing any code

Comment: How do you register the global events?